# Design of mobile app and server dealing with different size of photos

Tags: android, ios, django, image, image-processing

I don't know this title is clearly reflect the question content. Please help rephrase if you think it is confusing. Thanks!

This is a generic question about some common architecture. I am working on a Android app that can take and share photo just like Instagram. And I have a backend web service powered by Django.

The issue I am facing is, in the app, I will need to show **different resolution of image** (for example, thumbnails for profile image, mid-resolution for previews, and full resolution for expanded image views.) I want to ask a common pattern about how to make this happen.

I have two proposals on doing this task, and not sure which way I should go:

1.When user upload photos from the mobile app, I can compress it locally and send 3 different sizes (low res thumbnails, mid res, and high res). So server side can store them and return them back in different cases. **The Con of this approach** that I can think about is it will drain more user's data usage because now user will need to send multiple images. It may also cause uploading take more time and higher impact in user experience.

2.When user upload photos from the mobile app, they only upload the original image. The server side logic will do the compression for each income image, and store them accordingly. **The Con of this approach** is server may need to carry a lot more workload. In this case, if user increases a lot, it may crash the server.

I am hoping to get some pointer on this issue, or any reference about this topic will be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Upload the full size image to the server and have the server do the heavy lifting. Create three version of the image (small medium and large) and store them on the server (or content delivery network).   Create a database table to keep track of the image id for each image and its various versions.

With android you wont know how powerful the phone running your app is, never assume it can handle whatever image manipulation you need, also try and keep network I/O as low as possible.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is a first resize in the mobile, just one, because you dont one to transfer  13Mpx picture and also you dont want in your server a picture   2 screens wide   (this is the first thing instagram does). After that, upload the file, and have the server doing the rest of the stuff.

- this avoid a lot of that usage
- ensures that will work fine in any device (every one has different capabilities, so you cant trust them for heavy work)
- You can change some decisions about settings or configurations, and all this is centralized, if you change any common behavior, you don't need all the devices to get the last version of the app.

About crashing the server, there is one first measure i would take:

- Don't do any operation, like re-sizing or making copies of the image in the moment of the upload, you can choose one of this approaches:

  - Do it when there is a request for the file. this is, dont do it when the user sends it, but when somebody needs it.
  - Do it in a continuos backgorund process, like a cronjob running every minute, for instance.
  - or a combination of the two, there is a process in the background doing the stuff for all the pending images, but if somebody enters in the website and they need an image that is not yet generated, it is generate in that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Alan - Think of smart phones as relatively dumb terminals made for purpose of consuming content. Most of the business logic and heavy processing should me implemented on server side.

In terms of architecture, you are facing scalability problem. You cannot expand cpu/memory or storage of a device to any level you want. However you can scale your servers horizontally or vertically by adding more ram/cores/disks etc. You can put cluster on server and have a farm of servers if data increases to that level.

So its always advisable to just upload the original image without locally processing. Locally processing also drains battery besides other downside you mentioned.

Again you business logic or processing technique changes, you have to redeploy all apps. Where as on server side such deployments are very well in your control.